# Open and write to file in assembly on mac

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

I'm learning 32 bit assembly on mac, and I've have been trying to write to a file on my desktop. I used this code:

```
global _start
section .data
path:   db  "/Users/jackliu/Desktop/test.txt",0
string: db  "hello",0
.len:   equ $ - string

section .text

_start:
mov eax, 5
push dword 2
push dword path
sub esp, 8
int 0x80
add esp, 16
mov ebx, eax

mov eax, 4
push dword string.len
push dword string
push dword ebx
sub esp, 4
int 0x80
add esp, 16

mov eax, 1
push 0
sub esp, 12
int 0x80
```

The file is empty and it already exists on my desktop. After running it, it doesn't change the file at all.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: You're correct. In os x, I read that you have to align the stack to the 16th bit, so that's what I am trying to do. I just tried it with your suggestions, but no luck.

Comment: Okay, it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MAC OS [int 0x80](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master) open system call is:

> 5 AUE_OPEN_RWTC   ALL { int open(user_addr_t path, int flags, int mode); }

Your code passes 2 parameters:

```
mov eax, 5       ; Open system call = 5
push dword 2     ; Read/Write flag
push dword path  ; Path
sub esp, 8       ; Alignment
int 0x80
```

Since you are opening an existing file specify a mode of 0 for the third parameter. Your code could look like this:

```
mov eax, 5       ; Open system call = 5
push dword 0     ; Mode = 0
push dword 2     ; Read/Write flag
push dword path  ; Path
sub esp, 4       ; Reserved space for system call
int 0x80
```

Comment: Okay, so I was experimenting some more with this. I deleted the file on my desktop. Then, I replaced `push dword 0` with `push dword 0666o`, and `push dword 2` with `push dword 0102o`. This is supposed to create the file on my desktop and then write "hello" to it, but nothing happened. Am I supposed to add anything else?

Comment: @JackLiu : `push dword 0102o` looks wrong. You sure you didn't mean `push dword 0102h` (hex instead of octal?)

Comment: I just tried it. It didn't work sadly. I was maybe thinking that the O_CREAT flag is different on mac than on other computers? I couldn't find any resources on it though.

Comment: Doh, I was thinking Linux. Should be `0202h` on OS/X. The best place to look for those types is in the system header in `/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h`

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks, but I don't have an include directory in my usr folder.

Comment: Okay, I just had to install some xcode stuff. The directory was there.